# Careers Link Bug

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

When I click on a link to a specific posting on the "Jobs near you" box, such as:

http://clc.stackoverflow.com/j/ct/83646?an=Y7zGOMuLjeGSh7MGAwMjIwPTPjdGhm9ubqudj6-1Z2JlYmBiYJRjYGTwcIYJ99ozQ4S5gMIsbAwMDCH_KxSYlxScET4EAA&ca=pTsfXCLGfHX&utm=%26utm_source%3Dstackoverflow.com%26utm_medium%3Dad%26utm_campaign%3Djobs-small-sidebar-orange-nearyou

I end up redirected to the address:

http://careers.stackoverflow.com.internal

Which obviously does not work.

If I click the "Jobs near you" title or use the "Stack Overflow Careers" link in the main menu, both work fine.

Comment: Cannot reproduce that. What's your setup, is it still the case?

Comment: Thanks for the report; will get some careers folks to take a look.

Comment: @Marc who stole Bret's diamond?! ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry, we've been making lots of changes to the way job ads are served, and occasionally bugs pop up. In this case, we were redirecting you to a `.internal` address which we use for internal API calls between services (as you could probably guess). Of course, that url is meaningless outside our network.

Anyway, it's fixed now. We're working on some testing to help prevent that happening in the future. Thanks for reporting it.